# How to add Sina Weibo activity feed to my page?

Tags: javascript, rest, service, social-media, weibo

The Chinese version of Facebook/Twitter is called Sina Weibo. I would like to fetch the activity feed of a specific company site in Weibo, and put it on the company web page.

I cannot use the topical wall widget since it might show random postings on the specified hash-tags, not official for the company (am I right?).

If there were an official RSS-solution of Weibo, that would have been all I needed to create a feed with custom design, but as far as I and Google knows there are none. Only third party sites are offering this.

If I could fetch the information via the API - Weibo REST services, it would be awesome. I will need to show only public postings meaning no login is required for page visitors.

Anyone got any ideas or experience of achieving this with Weibo?

Weibo Widget API - http://open.weibo.com/widget/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this api to get the latest weibos of one user.

> https://api.weibo.com/2/statuses/user_timeline.json

The following article may also be helpful
http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~lingwang/weiboguide/#openweiboacc

Answer (score 0):

You can read Weibo API english documentation : [Weibo API](http://open.weibo.com/wiki/API%E6%96%87%E6%A1%A3_V2/en)

But the last update was written on 2012. This maybe an error as the chinese update is recently done in 2017.

It requires you to register to get an API key.

*You may alternatively embed a Weibo widget from external providers such as this  [Weibo widget](https://www.dialogfeed.com/embed-weibo-feed-on-page-get-weibo-api-data-or-widget/)*